# Low Latency Aggregations on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We are ingesting a lot of time series metrics into our system. We can't handle the write load with our current infrastructure. So, we are evaluating cassandra.

#### More Information about our existing realtime system

- We collect application specific time series metrics
- We write them into a DB
- Here's a sample of data we track

> ```
> {
>   appId: 'applicationId', 
>   route: 'routeName', 
>   time: 1406845866304, 
>   resTime: 500, 
>   dbTime: 200
> }
> ```

- Then after data has been added, we are aggregating them into different resolutions over the time
- for an example, we have pre-aggregated data for 1minute, 30min, 3hour, day resolutions for every metric we track
- Then our front end app will ask different questions like below. We do adhoc aggregations to anser them.

  - give me the average resTime for this X time period
  - list me top 10 routes which has higher resTime over a given period of time

#### Concerns with Cassandra

We can do pre-aggregations with cassandra with running some background jobs. But we need to do adhoc queries under low latency (less then 5ms). With our pre-aggregated data, this seems trivial.

But since cassandra have no aggregation support, we need to find some other solution. We tried spark(without cassandra) with some in memory data sources. But it took more time to do the aggregation for a small amount data like this.

So, only viable option is to create an aggregation engine on top of cassandra. I just wanna know is there some other ways to do this or there are some existing solutions?

Comment: Could you make am example of data and how these are aggregated in your actual system?

Comment: What kind of metrics are you tracking? What aggregations are you looking to do?

Comment: Thank you guys. I've updated the question with more information.